# Sieve of Eratosthenes Speed Comparison: Python vs Julia

Tags: python, performance, julia

So I have a little sieve of Eratosthenes function written in both Python and Julia, and I'm comparing run times.

Here is the Python code:

```
import time

def get_primes(n):
    numbers = set(range(n, 1, -1))
    primes = []
    while numbers:
        p = numbers.pop()
        primes.append(p)
        numbers.difference_update(set(range(p*2, n+1, p)))
    return primes

start = time.time()
get_primes(10000)
print time.time() - start
```

And here is the Julia code:

```
function get_primes(n)
        numbers = [2:n]
        primes = Int[]
        while numbers != []
                p = numbers[1]
                push!(primes, p)
                numbers = setdiff(numbers, [p*i for i=1:int(n/p)])
        end
        return primes
end

@time get_primes(10000);
```

The Python code runs in about .005 seconds, while the Julia code takes about .5 seconds, so that means Python runs about 100x times faster. There's probably a perfectly logical reason for this, but I really have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Why are you using a set in python but an array in Julia?

Comment: Also, try timing the second run - the first time there is compilation overhead

Comment: @IainDunning, the Python code was taken verbatim from someone else, I rewrote it in Julia and cleaned it up a bit, but haven't done anything to clean up the Python code

Comment: @IainDunning, The timing was post compile.

Comment: I think the Python code is buggy. `set` doesn't have ordering, although it might *appear* to be ordered due to implementation details. The sieve very much requires the primes to be calculated in order.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: In Python the pop method for a set just pops the minimum element.

Comment: @user1378571 not according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.pop): "Remove and return **an arbitrary element** from the set."

Comment: @Mark Ransom: You're right, but for whatever reason the code works consistently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference is that in Python you're allocating a single set, `number`, and then modifying it in place, while in Julia, you're allocating a new array on every iteration of the loop. Another difference is that you're using a set in Python and an array in Julia (what Python calls a "list"). Let's change the Julia code to eliminate these two differences:

```
function get_primes(n)
    numbers = IntSet(2:n)
    primes = Int[]
    while !isempty(numbers)
        p = shift!(numbers)
        push!(primes, p)
        setdiff!(numbers, p:p:n)
    end
    return primes
end
```

With this change, on my system, the Julia code is 10x faster than the Python code (0.0005 vs. 0.0048 seconds). Note that I also used a range as the second argument of the `setdiff!` – it's both terser and faster (1.5x) than constructing an array with a comprehension.

A somewhat more idiomatic style of writing this in Julia would be to use an array of booleans, turning them on and off:

```
function eratosthenes(n)
    primes = fill(true,n)
    primes[1] = false
    for p = 2:n
        primes[p] || continue
        for i = 2:div(n,p)
            primes[p*i] = false
        end
    end
    find(primes)
end
```

The `find` at the end returns the indices where a vector is non-zero (i.e. true). On my machine, this is 5x faster (0.0001 seconds) than the other Julia version and 45x faster than the Python version.

Comment: I'm having problems with using getindex on Set.  Is that a recent change?

Comment: @waTeim: I had to change `Set(1:n)` to `Set([1:n]...)` and `p = numbers[1]` to `p = minimum(numbers)` to get the code to run, for me this makes the code now only 10x slower than python.  The first change could be a (very) recent build issue, but it doesn't seem like get_index should be a method that a set data structure has.

Comment: Hmm. I must have done something wrong when cutting and pasting code, because this now isn't working for me. Working on an update.

Comment: I think I accidentally timed the built-in `primes` function before and the previous version of the code never worked. Instead, I'm now using an `IntSet` and `shift!`, which does work and is reasonably fast. The idiomatic boolean array version now beats both the Julia and Python set versions by quite a bit.

Comment: how do you use `shift!` on a set?  Help says it pops the first item of a collection, but sets are not ordered and I get a method error when I try.  Also is your syntax for forming sets using range notation from a super recent build?

Comment: @user1378571 I thought so too, but it looks like ***IntSet*** is ordered

Answer (score 2):

#### Trying to use setdiff! instead of setdiff

With this code

```
function get_primes(n)
   numbers::Set{Int} = Set(2:n)
   primes::Array{Int64,1} = []
   while !isempty(numbers) 
      p = minimum(numbers)
      push!(primes,p);
      setdiff!(numbers,Set(p:p:n))
   end
   return primes
end
```

I got

```
julia> @time get_primes(10000);
elapsed time: 0.029556727 seconds (1656448 bytes allocated)
```

The other (original) version is indeed bad because it spends most of the time in setdiff re-hashing after the calculation -- my timings for the unaltered version were similar to OP's.  So it looks like **setdiff!** is perhaps 100x faster than **setdiff**, but accepts only ***Sets*** not ***Arrays***.

This is still 6x slower than python but 13x faster than when using **setdiff**.  However, if there were some way to maintain an ordered set and always take the first element, then it would likely be much faster because almost 90% of the time (209/235) is being spent finding the minimum of a set.

```
235 task.jl; anonymous; line: 96
 235 REPL.jl; eval_user_input; line: 54
  235 profile.jl; anonymous; line: 14
   209 /Users/jeffw/src/errata/julia/sive.jl; get_primes; line: 5
    2   reduce.jl; mapfoldl; line: 75
     2 dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 669
    207 reduce.jl; mapfoldl; line: 81
     1   reduce.jl; mapfoldl_impl; line: 54
      1 dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 670
     199 reduce.jl; mapfoldl_impl; line: 57
      10  dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 668
      132 dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 669
      12  dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 670
      27  dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 672
     7   reduce.jl; mapfoldl_impl; line: 58
   1   /Users/jeffw/src/errata/julia/sive.jl; get_primes; line: 6
   25  /Users/jeffw/src/errata/julia/sive.jl; get_primes; line: 7
    14 set.jl; setdiff!; line: 24
     1 dict.jl; skip_deleted; line: 669
```

#### Update changing to using IntSet and shift!

```
function get_primes(n)
   numbers::IntSet = IntSet(2:n)
   primes::Array{Int64,1} = []
   while !isempty(numbers)
      p = shift!(numbers)
      push!(primes,p);
      setdiff!(numbers,Set(p:p:n))
   end
   return primes 
end

julia> @time get_primes(10000);
elapsed time: 0.003691856 seconds (1463152 bytes allocated)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested many approaches and I have found this one as the fastest in 8 different tests.

```
# Julia 0.4.0 [Execution time = 95us (After warm up!!)]
function get_primes(n::Int64)
  numbers = fill(true,n)
  numbers[1] = false

  for i = 2:isqrt(n)
    if numbers[i]
      for j = i:div(n,i)
        numbers[i*j] = false
      end
    end
  end

  primes = find(numbers) # t=3-5us
  return primes
end

@time primes = get_primes(10000)
println(get_primes(100))
```

First Julia code on this page calculated n=10000 in about **1'000'000us** on my PC, while this one took about **95us** which is 10'000x faster.

```
# Python 3.4 [Execution time = 5ms (Every time)]
def get_primes(n):
  m = n+1
  numbers = [True for i in range(m)]
  for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))):
    if numbers[i]:
      for j in range(i*i, m, i):
        numbers[j] = False
  primes = []
  for i in range(2, m):
    if numbers[i]:
      primes.append(i)
  return primes

start = time.time()
primes = get_primes(10000)
print(time.time() - start)
print(get_primes(100))
```

Python test

```
# Python n=100e6 [Execution time 52.906s]
start = time.time()
get_primes(int(100e6))
print(time.time() - start)
```

Julia test

```
# Julia n=100e6 [Execution time 3.694s]
@time get_primes(convert(Int64,100e6))
```

The difference is now less. **Julia vs Python is about 12x faster.**