# What are Python-Style List Comprehensions and Generators Considered in Julia by Core Julia Devs?

Tags: python, julia

If I search the Julia 1.0.0 on-line documentation for `list`, the first hit is:

> Unordered lists can be written by prepending each item in a list with either *, +, or -.

This is in a topic titled “Markdown syntax”, clearly not related to Python-style lists.

Another hit, further down is:

> Noteworthy differences from Python (section)

I did not see the word `list` mentioned in this section.

A search for “list comprehension”, provided the 10th hit as:

**Comprehensions (section)**

starting with,

> Comprehensions provide a general and powerful way to construct arrays.

The mention of arrays seems to imply Python-style list comprehensions can be done with Julia arrays.

Down one heading is **Generator Expressions**

> Comprehensions can also be written without the enclosing square brackets, producing an object known as a generator.

This sounds much like a Python-style generator.

Do the developers of Julia consider Julia's arrays (1-dim) to be essentially equivalent to Python lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes, but faster.**

[@StefanKarpinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659248/stefankarpinski), co-creator of Julia, made the following comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027495/sieve-of-eratosthenes-speed-comparison-python-vs-julia/25028103#25028103)

> Another difference is that you're using a set in Python and an array in Julia (what Python calls a ‘list’)

So according to Stefan, “an array” (probably means 1-dimensional array) is “what Python calls a ‘list’”

For a simple example, suppose we want to find the product, `P`, of 10 million ratios, `R`, where the numerator of each term is `4n^2`, and the denominator of each term is one less than the numerator, `R = num/(num - 1)`, where `n` = 1 to 10 million.

Without trying to do any optimizations of any kind here is a Python-style list comprehension in Julia 1.0.0:

```
julia> P = prod([4n^2/(4n^2 - 1) for n in 1:10_000_000])
1.5707962875230395
```

Running this in the Julia 1.0.0 REPL is very fast, essentially instantaneous on my laptop.  This is not a benchmark test, but running similar code, modified for Python, with Python 3.6 in the REPL in PyCharm is notably slower.

```
import numpy as np
P = np.prod([4*n**2/(4*n**2 - 1) for n in range(1, 10_000_001)])  
P
1.5707962875404267
```

Just visually guessing at speed, Julia is much more than 10 times faster for this list comprehension.

What about generators in Julia?

Just remove the square brackets inside the `prod` function call:

```
julia> P = prod(4n^2/(4n^2 - 1) for n in 1:10_000_000)
1.5707962875404267
```

Julia’s answer is instantaneous on my laptop.

This is not a speed comparison between Python and Julia, so I will leave Python at this point.

Julia’s `2n` for `2 * n` is a nice feature.  For example, try `2P`:

```
julia> 2P
3.1415925750808533
```

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: It is worth to comment that Python's list is rather a `Vector{Any}` and not just any 1-D array in Julia.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński What would the difference be?  And thanks for the comment.

Comment: The difference is that a ``Vector{Any}`` can store any type of value. A ``Vector{Int}`` can only store integers.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense.  Thanks.

Comment: The other thing to note is that `Vector{Any}` will be approximately as fast as list in Python and `Vector{Int}` can be expected to be faster as Julia is able to specialize the code taking into account type information.

Comment: And along those lines, a NumPy array is the same as a `Vector{Float64}`. Julia's single array type and type specializations handles the standard array types via type parameters.

Comment: Note that your code `prod([4n^2/(4n^2 - 1) for n in 1:10_000_000])` first generates an array, then summarises it. That takes 37 ms on my machine. You don't have to materialize the array, which is what a generator is for. `prod(4n^2/(4n^2 - 1) for n in 1:10_000_000)` (without the square brackets) takes 13 ms on my machine.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard The visual comparisons mentioned in  my answer were that in both the comprehension case and the generator case Julia was much faster than Python 3.6 comparable results.  Actually, I was surprised how much faster Julia was than Python in the generator case.  I had assumed the Python generator would have some optimizations, but I did not see much of that.  Your numbers agree with my visual sense.  Julia comprehensions/generators were both essentially instant, < 100 ms for humans,  Thanks for providing the Julia comprehension vs. Julia generator timing comparison.

Comment: Thanks to all for comments.  I am trying to understand vectors and arrays in Julia.  This helps, `julia> Vector{1} == Array{1, 1}
true`  So my newbie understanding is that a Julia Vector is just a one-dimensional array.  Is that all there is to it, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's exactly right. A `Vector{T}` is just a short form of `Array{T, 1}`, nothing else.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Thanks!  Exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Julia arrays are N-dimensional, `Vector{T}` (AKA `Array{T, 1}`) is a one dimensional array of type `T`. Python lists are homologous to `Vector{Any}`, notice however that array comprehensions/generators in Julia are also N-dimensional:

Comment: `[i for i in 1:10]` returns a `Vector{Int}` of length 10, `[i*j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10]` returns a 10x10 `Matrix{Int}` (aka `Array{Int, 2}`) and `[i*j*k for i in 1:10, j in 1:10, k in 1:2]` returns a 10x10x2 3D array `Array{Int, 3}`.

Comment: They also accept an `if` clause like in Python (using an `if` clause `[i*j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10 if i > 5]` or `[i*j for i in 1:10 for j in 1:10]` (notice the **`for`** instead of **comma** to separate the ranges in the last example) will return a 1D array).

Comment: @SalchiPapa Very helpful comments.  Thanks!